# Name of this kind of word puzzle: find a word with string of letters in the middle

Tags: puzzle-identification

This is a puzzle I have used with my school students, and I am wondering if it already has a name. The idea is to give a string of (often three) letters and to find a word with that string of letters in the middle. Usually I just write the string with a * before and after, saying you have to replace the *'s with any nonempty strings of letters, even not the same strings, to make a real word.

For example:
* rfl *
* atm *
* pbo *

Is there a name for this kind of puzzle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, I've played this before!  It's called "the HIPE game" after the favorite combination of its inventor, Peter Winkler, and is described in his article, ["A Wordy Digression: The Game of HIPE" (PDF)](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2083&context=wordways). 
(This appears to be a chapter from his book, *Mathematical Mind-Benders*.)

The solution to `*HIPE*` appears in the linked article.

Comment: I think it would be good to have the author's name here in the post.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the game [*Mischmasch*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mXo8Mg16e08C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42), invented by Lewis Carroll. (Googling for the game Mischmasch is tricky because Carroll also produced a magazine called *Mischmasch*, so add words such as "word" and "game" to your search string.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, though I am going to accept the HIPE answer, because I don't want to include Carroll's scoring element. (Mind you, when I introduce it I will reference Carroll.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a name for it.

How about

> Wordpad (hmm is that trademarked?);
>  Re**word**ing; or
>  Urroun.

Some answers for examples

> shortest I can find:
>  Pu**rfl**e (6) - to finish with an ornamental border.
>  B**atm**an (6) - an orderly assigned to serve a British military officer (or the cartoon character of course).
>  U**pbo**il (6) - (archaic) to boil up.
>
>  longest (non-chemical) I can find:
>  supe**rfl**uorescence (17) - the collective emission of fluorescent light by an ensemble of excited atoms or ions.
>  sub**atm**ospheric (14) - less than atmospheric pressure.
>  cla**pbo**arding (12) - to cover with clapboards (wooden boards that may cover the outside of a house)